# Running a JDBC oracle java programm from cmd line

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, command-line

I have the following problem with running JDBC oracle from command line. When I run the following code in IntelliJ, it works like a charm, but when I try to run it via commandline with

```
java UserInterface filldb
```

I get the follwing error:

> An error occured: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

How do I run this program from command line?

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;

import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;

import javax.security.auth.callback.ConfirmationCallback;


final public class DatabaseDAO implements DAO {

    private String database;
    private String user;
    private String pass;

    // establish connection to database
    private Connection con;
    private Statement stmt;

    DatabaseDAO() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        // load drivers and save user data
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        database = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle-lab.cs.univie.ac.at:1521:lab";
        user = "*****";
        pass = "*****";
    }

    public void openConnection(String user, String database, String pass) throws SQLException{
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(database, user, pass);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
    }

    public void openConnection() throws SQLException{
        openConnection(user, database, pass);
    }

    public void closeConnection() { //local exception handling so method can be called in finally block, seems safer
        try {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Fehler beim Verbindungsabbau in DatabaseDAO.closeConnection(): " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }

    private void printTableSize(String tablename) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tablename);
        if (rs.next()) {
            int count = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("Number of datasets in table " + tablename + ": "+ count);
        }
        rs.close();
    }

    private boolean insertSQL (String values, String tablename) throws SQLException {
        String insertSql = "INSERT INTO " + tablename + " VALUES " + values;
        stmt.executeUpdate(insertSql);
        return true;
    }

    public void flushTable(String tablename) throws SQLException{
        stmt.executeQuery("DELETE FROM " + tablename);
    }

    public void flushDatabase() throws  SQLException {
        for ( Relation r : Relation.values())
            flushTable(r.toString());
    }
/*
    public ArrayList<String> getDatabaseEntry(int type, List<String> key) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IllegalArgumentException {

    }
*/
/*
    public boolean deleteDatabaseEntry(List<String> key) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IllegalArgumentException{}
 */
    public boolean saveDatabaseEntry(Relation type, DatabaseObject entry){
        boolean success = false;
        try{
            switch (type) {
                case Firma: {
                    Firma e = (Firma)entry;
                    String values = "(" + e.getSteuerbuchummer() + "," + e.getName() + "," + e.getFirmenbuchnummer() + ")";
                    printTableSize(Relation.Firma.toString());
                    success = insertSQL(values, Relation.Firma.toString());
                } break;
                case Template: {
                    Template e = (Template) entry;
                    String values = "(" + e.getUrl() + "," + e.getSprache() + "," + e.getIp() + ")";
                    printTableSize(Relation.Template.toString());
                    success = insertSQL(values, Relation.Template.toString());
                } break;
                case verwendet: {
                    verwendet e = (verwendet) entry;
                    String values = "(" + e.getSteuerbuchummer() + "," + e.getUrl() + ")";
                    printTableSize(Relation.verwendet.toString());
                    success = insertSQL(values, Relation.verwendet.toString());
                } break;
                case Unterseite: {
                    Unterseite e = (Unterseite) entry;
                    String values = "(" + e.getUrl() + "," + e.getPfad() + ")";
                    printTableSize(Relation.Unterseite.toString());
                    success = insertSQL(values, Relation.Unterseite.toString());
                } break;
                case Verkaufsseite: {
                    Verkaufsseite e = (Verkaufsseite) entry;
                    String values = "(" + e.getUrl() + "," + e.getPfad() + ", " + e.getTitel() + ")";
                    printTableSize(Relation.Verkaufsseite.toString());
                    success = insertSQL(values, Relation.Verkaufsseite.toString());
                } break;
                case UserAccount: {
                    UserAccount e = (UserAccount) entry;
                    String values = "(" + e.getEmail() + "," + e.getUserID() + ", " + e.getBankdaten() + ", " + e.getAdresse() + ")";
                    printTableSize(Relation.UserAccount.toString());
                    success = insertSQL(values, Relation.UserAccount.toString());
                } break;
                case befreundet: {
                    befreundet e = (befreundet) entry;
                    String values = "(" + e.getUserID1() + "," + e.getUserID2() + ")";
                    printTableSize(Relation.befreundet.toString());
                    success = insertSQL(values, Relation.befreundet.toString());
                } break;
                case Produkt: {
                    Produkt e = (Produkt) entry;
                    String values = "(" + e.getProduktID() + "," + e.getPreis() + "," + e.getProduktname() + ")";
                    printTableSize(Relation.Produkt.toString());
                    success = insertSQL(values, Relation.Produkt.toString());
                } break;
                case kauftEin: {
                    kauftEin e = (kauftEin) entry;
                    String values = "(" + e.getUrl() + "," + e.getUserID() + "," + e.getPfad() + "," + e.getProduktID() + "," + e.getAnzahl() + ")";
                    printTableSize(Relation.kauftEin.toString());
                    success = insertSQL(values, Relation.kauftEin.toString());
                } break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter ungueltig in DatabaseDAO.saveDatabaseEntry(Relation type, DatabaseObject entry).");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Fehler beim Einfuegen des Datensatzes in DatabaseDAO.saveDatabaseEntry(Relation type, DatabaseObject entry): " + e.getMessage());
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }

    public Connection getCon() {
        return con;
    }

    public Statement getStmt() {
        return stmt;
    }
}
```

Here is the main class:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class UserInterface {
    private enum Command {
        filldb, flushdb
    }

    private static final Command checkInput(String s){
        Command[] command = Command.values();
        for(int i = 0; i < command.length; i++) if (command[i].toString().equals(s)) return command[i];
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Commandline Parameter nicht erkannt. Kommandos: filldb, flushdb");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DatabaseDAO db = null;
        try {
            Command command = checkInput(args[0]);
            switch(command){
                case filldb: {
                    System.out.println("Initializing DB.");

                    db = new DatabaseDAO();
                    db.openConnection();

                    System.out.println("Done.\nGenerating data and filling DB (this may take a few minutes).");
                    TestDataGenerator tdg =  new TestDataGenerator(db);
                    tdg.testData(Relation.Firma, 2000);
                    tdg.testData(Relation.Template, 2000);
                    tdg.testData(Relation.verwendet, 500);
                    tdg.testData(Relation.Unterseite, 1000);
                    tdg.testData(Relation.Verkaufsseite, 1000);
                    tdg.testData(Relation.UserAccount, 3000);
                    tdg.testData(Relation.Produkt, 4000);
                    tdg.testData(Relation.befreundet, 500);
                    tdg.testData(Relation.kauftEin, 1000);

                    System.out.println("Done. DB is now filled with several thousand entries.");
                } break;
                case flushdb: {
                    System.out.println("Flushing DB");
                    db.flushDatabase();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Ein Fehler ist bei der Kommunikation mit der Datenbank aufgetreten: "+ e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Klasse nicht gefunden: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten: "+ e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        finally{
            if (!db.equals(null)) db.closeConnection();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the JDBC driver (and any other dependent libraries) are within the class path. If this project has been exported to a Jar, you'll need to make sure that the `class-path` element in the `META/manifiest.mf` file exists AND that the jars are available at the specified, relative, location

Comment: Maybe you need to use the -cp argument in your command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a classpath that contains the Oracle driver, Java is currently only looking at the current directory and its own runtime for classes.

For windows

```
java -cp .;C:\dummypath\ojdbc8.jar UserInterface filldb
```

For Linux

```
java -cp .:/dummypath/ojdbc8.jar UserInterface filldb
```

The `.` specifies makes sure the current directory is still on the classpath, and `C:\dummypath\` or `/dummypath/` needs to be replaced with the real location of your Oracle driver jar.

Sidenote: I notice your class `UserInterface` is not in a package, this may suffice for trivial programs, but you should really get in the habit of using packages.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your advice regarding compiling and running the proramm from commandline, yet i havent been successful yet. The error for now looks like:

java -cp .:/home/lorenz/Code/dbs_java_l/dbs_java_l/ojdbC4.jar UserInterface filldb
Initializing DB.
Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

When i try to compile with your options i get:

 javac -cp .:/home/lorenz/Code/dbs_java_l/dbs_java_l/ojdbC4.jar UserInterface.java
./DatabaseDAO.java:4: error: package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
^
1 error

Comment: Thanks for the advice regarding packages though. YOu are right, larger programms should be ordered with packages.

Comment: There is no ojdbc4.jar (or at least, not in the standard naming of Oracle), maybe you meant ojdbc14.jar (which is very old, for Java 1.4)? Not relevant to this problem, but the fact you are importing `oracle.jdbc.driver.*` is usually a bad sign, you should almost never have to import driver specific packages.

Comment: This is working:

java -cp .:/home/lorenz/Code/dbs_java_l/dbs_java_l/ojdbc14.jar UserInterface filldb

Thanks for your help :).

Oh yeah and i am using ojdbc14.jar, but it s required by the project specifications, even if its old.

Regrading driver specific packages: you mean it is better to set the classpath variable so that my system autmatically knows where the the driver is? Would you be so kind to let ,me know how to do this :)?

Comment: @LorenzKummer No, that is not what I'm saying. The classpath evironment variable is hardly ever used, I mean that when using JDBC drivers, you should normally only have to use things from the `java.sql` package, it is normally not necessary to reference driver specific classes in your own code. I'm not sure how using a 15 year old driver can be a requirement in a real-world project, so I assume this is homework.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to the question is to specify a class path when executing the main class:

java -cp .:/home/lorenz/Code/dbs_java_l/dbs_java_l/ojdbc14.jar UserInterface filldb

Thanks everybody for their help.